# Tomcat 404 - Not Found

Tags: windows-7, tomcat

So my application on localhost is running: http:// localhost/hello-world/ I'm trying to port forward but this is where I'm getting 404 - not found. This is my tomcat settings [Tomcat settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTOpt.png)

Here is how I'm forwarding, this is a Verizon router: [Router settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilnoX.png)

Here is my ipconfig/all

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Nomi-PC
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 4:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : TAP-Windows Adapter V9
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-FF-D6-52-BE-85
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Marvell Yukon 88E8057 Family PCI-E Gigabi
t Ethernet Controller #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-1F-BC-08-D7-17
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::803b:93a9:deea:8a3a%13(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.232(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 301998012
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1F-63-DC-5F-00-1F-BC-08-D7-18

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : fios-router.home
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Marvell Yukon 88E8057 Family PCI-E Gigabi
t Ethernet Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-1F-BC-08-D7-18
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{36A2D241-01E7-4C03-B078-4FD3BC13F10F}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{D652BE85-DB36-4885-A847-A42EFA046BDE}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:5ef5:79fb:24f2:a94:93cc:a317(Prefe
rred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::24f2:a94:93cc:a317%14(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.fios-router.home:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

I have also tried with ip 192.168.1.232 The one in the screenshot is from "whatsmyip"

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I am not sure why you are using your hosts file - it should be irrelevant for this, that's just for the computer you're working on. For the "Forwarded IP" you need to use the 192.168.1.232 address. Also look around on the web interface of your Verizon router to find out what it thinks its IP is

Comment: My router says its IP address: 108.51.92.232

Comment: The IP forwarded needs to be the 192.168 address. Set the Host name in tomcat to be that address. Also look at this answer and copy this config to your equivalent file, but change the ports to 80. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21304208

Comment: I'd like a bit more explanation please. I'm still stuck at the same thing. I was able to run my tomcat using the connector. I am using the 192.168.1.232 to forward the port 80. But I'm still getting the same 404 not found.